# Error compiling c using gcc on AIX

Tags: c, gcc, aix

I'm trying to build a simple c application using gcc on aix

```
gcc -I. -c hello.c -o hello.o
gcc -o helloWorld hello.o -L helloHelper.so -ldl
```

I get the following errors

```
ld 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .PrintHello
```

PrintHello is a method in the library helloHelper.

I can build the application in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-L` is for indicating directories where to search for libraries. To link a dynamic library directly, just put it in the linker command:

```
gcc -o helloWorld hello.o helloHelper.so -ldl
```

Other option would be to use `-lhelloHelper` but then the library should be called `libhelloHelper.so`.

Comment: Good catch on the name. Missed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gcc -o helloworld hello.o -L. -lhelloHelper -ldl
```